# Iterate over OsString characters

Tags: string, rust, iterator

With `String`, we have the `.chars()` method to retrieve an iterator over that variable's characters.

How can I do the same thing with `OsString`? E.g.

```
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::ffi::OsString;

pub fn ostring_to_chars(string: OsString) {
    string.chars().collect::<Vec<OsString>>();
}
```

Comment: By characters, do you mean bytes? For characters, you need to know what the encoding is.

Comment: no, characters. basically, the file I'm processing is a pseudo-binary file, which contains a number of integers stored as characters. Some of them are above the 255 value, meaning that they get stored in more than one byte while the rest are only 1 byte in length. I don't want to have to figure out which byte belongs to which integer, which is what I'd have to do if I used a `&[u8]` instead of an `OsString`.

Comment: Ry: saw you edited comment just now. Do you think it would be better to process this as a byte array? Because this file is mostly UTF-8 *except* for various metadata which may or may not be valid Unicode.

Comment: Yes, that does sound better.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll try that instead, using a fixed data type (u16) instead of two (u8 and u16), so each integer will be stored in exactly two bytes.

Comment: Still, I'd like this question to be answered. Searching in the documentation yielded no results for this.

Comment: Try slicing the `OsString`, where you think you'll have valid characters to get an [`OsStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html), and then try to get an [`&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str). Note that the last step of validating unicode is an `O(n)` operation.

Comment: It seems that your question could be an X/Y problem; what you really want to know is how to iterate over code points, where the source strings are inconsistently encoded? If so, you could find WTF8 useful: https://docs.rs/wtf8/0.0.3/wtf8/

Comment: Do you agree that this can be rephrased to ask about bytes instead of characters? Because obviously there's no way to define "characters" for a string with no consistent encoding. Or what do you mean by *I'd like this question to be answered*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pub fn ostring_to_chars(string: OsString) {
    let data = string.into_string().unwrap();
    for char in data.chars() {
        println!("{}", char);
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably won't work for the OP's use case, because "the string(s) I'm processing comes from a file, which may or may not contain valid UTF-8." invalid UTF-8 would cause `string.into_string().unwrap()` to panic.

Comment: This doesn't resolve anything, you're just converting from `OsString` to `String` in a way it can fail. An answer saying one way is to convert to string using `into_string`/`to_str` or `into_string_lossy`/`to_str_lossy` with the good and bad information about each would already be much, much better